# Restoring Typescript Definition Nuget Packages

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, nuget

I'm currently working on a new project that uses Typescript for all client side code. I use a number of pure JavaScript libraries to have them work with my Typescript. I used Nuget to pull in the *.d.ts files via the following package manager commands.

An example package manager command:

> Install-Package angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 2.0.2

This works a treat and after installing all my Nuget packages a file is created called **packages.config** in the project directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="angular-translate.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.9.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="0.0.9" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

My Visual Studios project now has the following directories after the packages have been installed:

```
Scripts\
    typings\
        angularjs\         (contains relivant files)
        angular-translate\ (contains relivant files)
        bootstrap\         (contains relivant files)
        jquery\            (contains relivant files)
```

Now **my problem** is when someone else tries to clone my repository visual studios will try and automatically restore the Nuget packages but installs them in the following fashion:

```
Packages\
   angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.2.0.2\
       Content\
           Scripts\
               typings\
                   angularjs\ (contains relivant files)

   angular-translate.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.0.9.0\
       Content\
           Scripts\
               typings\
                   angularjs\ (contains relivant files)

   bootstrap.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.0.0.9\
       Content\
           Scripts\
               typings\
                   angularjs\ (contains relivant files)

   jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped.1.4.0\
       Content\
           Scripts\
               typings\
                   angularjs\ (contains relivant files)
```

I have read over a number of stackoverflow threads and the Nuget documentation but can't really seem to find a solution to where I can run a command on the new repo machine and it will restore the files back to the configuration I had on the original machine.

Ideally I would like to avoid having to write and *.bat file that will transform the file structure to the way I want.

Comment: Jason might have a better idea. You can get his interest by reporting an issue here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/NugetAutomation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are experiencing one of common [Nuget misconceptions](http://jeffhandley.com/archive/2013/12/09/nuget-package-restore-misconceptions.aspx). Problem here is that (Automatic) Nuget Restore is not the same as Install-Package. Aim of Nuget Restore is to download and unpack packages. It will not restore content of your project or solution folders. Read article for more detail on why. There is a lot of people mad about this behavior, but this is the choice of Nuget developers.

A number of solution is mentioned in comments to [this issue](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2094). I personally use `Install-Package MSBuild.NugetContentRestore` which is all I need to resolve content files issue.

Hope this helps.