# TypeScript Setup, Configuration, Versions and Packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio, typescript, msbuild, nuget

Though I've been working with TypeScript for about a year, I haven't yet had to create and configure any greenfield projects using it.  I'm trying to do this now, and am finding the number of variables to be overwhelming.  I seem to be unable to find clear and authoritative answers about how best to set things up for a given set of circumstances (i.e. .Net version, TS version, VS version, etc).  Thus, I am confused and have questions about a few different, but related things.  I'm teetering on the edge of that space where I'm not quite sure what questions to ask, but I'm going to try anyway.

First, I want to specify my particular development circumstances:

- I'm using Visual Studio 2015, Pro and Community editions.  This is unlikely to change in the immediate future.
- The projects I normally work on target .Net Framework versions 4.5.x and 4.6.x and this is also unlikely to change soon.
- I require at least TypeScript version 2.0.6.0, but would welcome the chance to be able to target newer versions as they become available.

**Questions:**

1. How do I install and target multiple versions of TypeScript?  My original experience with using TypeScript required downloading TypeScript as a standalone installation. The installation results in TypeScript appearing in the list of VS "Extensions and Updates."  This seems to imply that only one version of TypeScript can be used on a given machine.  So then, how do you support different projects that might use different versions?
2. What are the NuGet packages published by the TypeScriptTeam (Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler, Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild) supposed to be used for?  Are these the answer to the above question?  Are they meant to replace the standalone-single-version-installation I described previously? The TypeScript projects I currently work on (but did not configure) do not have these packages.
3. Is NuGet the right place to get type definitions for libraries?  While setting things up, I grabbed several such packages for libraries I use (Knockout, jQuery, etc).  However, in spending the last couple days researching TypeScript setup and configuration, I came across [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414789/restoring-typescript-definition-nuget-packages), which, in turn, led me to [this project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/NugetAutomation), the ReadMe of which seems to imply that NuGet is no longer the right place to go for type definitions.  If my inference is correct, what's the best way to go about getting them?  To be clear, the SO question linked above is about NuGet not restoring script files.  I am not confused about that part.
4. Why don't I have the `.jsproj` file?  While researching all of this, I've found numerous mentions of this file and things that need to be edited in it, yet, I don't have that file in any of my solutions.  Is that limited to .Net Core solutions?  If so, what's the equivalent in the .Net Framework?

Comment: Uh oh. I feel a tumbleweed badge coming!

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How do I install and target multiple versions of TypeScript?

You could download the TypeScript.exe release from the following website:

**http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593**

After download some version of typeScript.exe, then install it. You can find them in the path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`:

[image]

After that, you will have several versions of Typescript installed on your machine. So each project in Visual Studio can be configured to use different version by specifying that version in project file.

[image]

Besides, in Visual Studio 2017, TypeScript updates are applied slightly differently than in Visual Studio 2015

> `In Visual Studio 2017, TypeScript updates are applied slightly
>   differently than in Visual Studio 2015, however you can now have
>   multiple TypeScript versions installed and choose specific versions
>   for each of your projects.`

You can refer [this Wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Updating-TypeScript-in-Visual-Studio-2017) for more detail info.

> 2. What are the NuGet packages published by the TypeScriptTeam (Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler, Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild) supposed to be used for? Are these the answer to the above question? Are they meant to replace the standalone-single-version-installation I described previously? The TypeScript projects I currently work on (but did not configure) do not have these packages.

AFAIK, with old version of Typescript installed from nuget package, VS used the path to know which version of typescript it should use to compile. If you are using Visual Studio 2013 or later you will need to install TypeScript. Since you are using Visual Studio 2015, that package would not replace the standalone-single-version-installation. The reason for TypeScript projects you currently work on without these packages is that **you must have install the TypeScript SDK on your machine**.

> 3. Is NuGet the right place to get type definitions for libraries?

NuGet should be the right place to get type definitions for libraries, if you have any problem about it, you can open a new thread about it. We need to analyze the specific reason why NuGet is not in right place to get type definitions for libraries.

> 4. Why don't I have the .jsproj file?

The .jsproj is for project type "`Blank App (Apache Cordova)`". When you create a Blank App (Apache Cordova) project: File->New->Project...->TypeScript. You will find the project file should be .jsproj.

You have too many questions in one thread, I suggest you can ask one question in one thread.

Hope this helps.